# Backend .netcore app not reachable from frontend angular site

Tags: angular, apache, asp.net-core, centos7

I want to build an application which is hosted in a Centos7 linux machine. It will have a site in Angular as FrontEnd which will be calling the API which is a .NetCore app in the same server.

The .NetCore runs in the port 21214 specified like this in the program.cs

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseKestrel(
                (Action<KestrelServerOptions>)(
                options => options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 21214)))
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

and in the etc/httpd/conf.d/CoreSite.conf it is specified like this

```
<VirtualHost *:21214>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:21215/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:21215/
    ErrorLog /etc/httpd/BackEnd-error.log
    CustomLog /etc/httpd/BackEnd-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

The FrontEnd site runs in port 80, published in the default httpd folder(/var/www/html) and published with this command :

ng build --prod --base-href http://***public ip of the server***

In the etc/httpd/conf.d/FrontEndSite.conf it is specified like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorDocument 404 /Error404.html
    ErrorLog /etc/httpd/FrontEnd-error.log
    CustomLog /etc/httpd/FrontEnd-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try calling the API from the Front END I get the following error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The ports of the BackEnd site are opened on the firewall of the machine and both sites are running without errors.

EDIT
I configured CORS on the BackEnd site as follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddCors(options =>
{
options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin",
builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://mypublicip"));
});
}
```

and added 
***[EnableCors("AllowMyOrigin")]*** 
on the controller and method being called

After these changes I got the same result

EDIT 2

I tried running the same call from the FrontEnd having the BackEnd application not running and got the same error. I doubt the call is not getting at all to the BackEnd

Comment: do you configured CORS?

Comment: Maybe not, all the configuration I have done is written in the question.

Comment: Try to configure CORS on you backend server first.

Comment: Updated the post with the details of cors. Had same result

Comment: you need to configure the CORS on the startup method, not on the controller, so it can be applied to the hub endpoint by SignalR.

Comment: The part of the code that I added on the edit 1 is written in the Startup.cs 

I don't have configured SignalR and am not accessing BackEnd with SignalR, but as a REST API